# How to return the first character of a variable in gmake

Tags: string, makefile, gnu-make

Using GNU's make, I'd like to extract the first character of a variable.  Currently I'm using the shell function to have `bash` perform the substring.  I'm wanting to know if there is a way using gmake's built-ins to do the same.

```
DIR=/user/$(shell echo "$${USER:0:1}")/$(USER)/
```

Comment: If you can guarantee that $DIR will only be expanded in a recipe, what's wrong with your first definition? (tweaked slightly)

DIR = /user/$${USER:0:1}/$$USER/
all:
     echo "USER: [$$USER] DIR: [${DIR}]"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not very satisfying, and you'd have to add to `$(INITIALS)` until you were happy, but:

```
INITIALS := a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
U := $(strip $(foreach a,$(INITIALS),$(if $(USER:$a%=),,$a)))

DIR = /user/$(U)/$(USER)/
```

Perhaps the sensible approach would be to take note of the `:=` usages in the above, and amend your simple version to `DIR := ...$(shell ...)...` so that the shell command is only invoked once.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Functions is a comprehensive list of everything you can do with gmake builtins.

It does not appear to be possible to extract the first character without `$(shell)`, unfortunately.