# Get the first letter of a make variable

Tags: gnu-make

Is there a better way to get the first character of a GNU `make` variable than

```
FIRST=$(shell echo $(VARIABLE) | head -c 1)
```

(which is not only unwieldy but also calls the external shell)?

Comment: GNU Make has no built-in substring functionality, so I don't think this is easy or obvious.  Maybe you could come up with something involving `$(patsubst)` but I wasn't able to.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703881/how-to-return-the-first-character-of-a-variable-in-gmake

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is pretty horrible, but at least it doesn't invoke `shell`:

```
$(eval REMAINDER := $$$(VAR))          # variable minus the first char
FIRST := $(subst $(REMAINDER),,$(VAR)) # variable minus that
```

Comment: I see what you did there. That's an interesting hack indeed, and it would break if for some reason `$($FIRST)` was non-empty, so if the first letter is itself a defined variable, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Anaphory, yes, it would. I don't see any way to prevent that.

Answer (score 3):

The [GNU Make Standard Library](http://gmsl.sourceforge.net/) provides a `substr` function

**substr**

```
Arguments: 1: A string
           2: Start offset (first character is 1)
           3: Ending offset (inclusive)
Returns:   Returns a substring
```

I haven't tested it, but `$(call substr,$(VARIABLE),1,1)` should work

Comment: I reckon that should be `$(call substr,$(VARIABLE),1,1)`.

Comment: gmsl doesn't seem to work well with automake. I get a bunch of errors about mismatched if/else/endif, after just adding the line `include gmsl`.

Comment: @CraigMcQueen, 1) oops, thanks, fixed. 2) can't help you with that, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Since I came across this in my own search and didn't find what I was looking for here is what I ended up using to parse a hex number that could be applied to any known set of characters

```
letters := 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f
nextletter = $(strip $(foreach v,$(letters),$(word 2,$(filter $(1)$(v)%,$(2)) $v)))
```

then

```
INPUT := 40b3
firstletter := $(call nextletter,,$(INPUT))
secondletter := $(call nextletter,$(firstletter),$(INPUT))
thirdletter := $(call nextletter,$(firstletter)$(secondletter),$(INPUT))
```

etc.

It's ugly but it's shell agnostic