# How to print a single character in a variable in omakefile

Tags: omake

In my omakefile, I have a variable name 'CHECK' with variable value 'hello'. My question is how can I read/print only 'h'?

Example:

Input:

```
CHECK = hello
```

Output:

```
h
```

I know how to print entire variable `$(CHECK)`.

What I tried:

Input:

```
CHECK = hello
FIRST=$(shell echo $(CHECK) | head -c 1)
```

Output of FIRST VARIABLE:

```
(Empty)
```

Comment: Please, avoid using tags which are unrelated to your problem. If you don't know meaning of a specific tag, then hover a cursor over it and read its description.

Comment: @Tsyvarev No , i tried  this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12798666/get-the-first-letter-of-a-make-variable   , not working

Comment: Please, show (add description to the question post) what **exactly** have you **tried** and your **results** of those attempts.

Comment: @Tsyvarev  Added Description what i tried , thank you

Comment: BTW, why have you reverted "omake" tag? As you could find in the description of that tag, it denotes build system which is **different** from Make. And another tag of your question, "makefile", refers to the writting files for Make. So, which **language** you are programming for?

Comment: @Tsyvarev - omake language

Comment: According to [omake documentation](http://projects.camlcity.org/projects/dl/omake-0.10.5/doc/html/omake-quickstart.html#sec3), in OMake a script file is referred as "OMakefile". Please, edit your question to use proper terminology ("OMakefile" instead of "makefile") and remove "makefile" tag: this tag has noting common with your question.

Comment: If you really are using omake, then that is not the same as GNU make, they are entirely different things.  You can't use GNU make syntax (such as `$(shell ...)`) in an omakefile, it won't work.  You need to restrict your searches to omake-specific results and read the omake documentation, not the GNU make documentation.

Comment: @MadScientist: The question contains `$(shell ...)` attempt as an evidence why the duplicate, suggested by me, is not suited. Initially the question post was massively mistagged, so I incorrectly interpreted it as being about Make. This is why I suggested a Make duplicate. Only later I found out that the question is actually about omake, not Make.

Comment: Agreed.  My comment was directed at the OP (Kamaraj).